# Need help understanding perl code

Tags: perl

I am a beginner in perl.
Just wanted to understand the following code.

```
sub get_files {
    foreach my $customer (keys %customers){
        lg("Getting files from ftp for customer $customer", "LOG");
        my $ftp_server = $customers{$customer}{'FtpServer'};
        my $ftp_user   = $customers{$customer}{'FtpUser'};
        my $ftp_pass   = $customers{$customer}{'FtpPass'};
        my $datadir    = $datafiles.$customer."/";


        `$get_files $ftp_server $ftp_user $ftp_pass $datadir`;

    }
}
```

What does last line in the above subroutine tells?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It invokes the command that's in the string `$get_files`, passing the command the remaining strings as parameters.

*Usually* it's used if you want to capture the resulting output and store it in a variable.  In this case where the result is being discarded it would be more usual to use `system` instead:

```
system $get_files, $ftp_server, $ftp_user, $ftp_pass, $datadir;
```

although if the command does then produce any output it'll appear on-screen instead of being absorbed by the back-ticks operator.